# Как можно переделать 2 библиотеки .dll в .lib

Tags: c++

Как можно переделать 2 библиотеки .dll в .lib, если они имеют такой код:

```
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // render
    LPCSTR            r1_name    = "xrRender_R1.dll";
    LPCSTR            r2_name    = "xrRender_R2.dll";

#ifndef DEDICATED_SERVER
    if (psDeviceFlags.test(rsR2) )    {
        // try to initialize R2
        Log                ("Loading DLL:",    r2_name);
        hRender            = LoadLibrary        (r2_name);
        if (0==hRender)    {
            // try to load R1
            Msg            ("...Failed - incompatible hardware.");
        }
    }
#endif

    if (0==hRender)        {
        // try to load R1
        psDeviceFlags.set    (rsR2,FALSE);
        renderer_value        = 0; //con cmd

        Log                ("Loading DLL:",    r1_name);
        hRender            = LoadLibrary        (r1_name);
        if (0==hRender)    R_CHK                (GetLastError());
        R_ASSERT        (hRender);
    }
```

Не подскажите пожалуйста?

Comment: Если имеется ввиду переделать в статическую библиотеку, то никак. Если в библиотеку импорта - возможны варианты.

Comment: _Если имеется ввиду переделать в статическую библиотеку, то никак. Если в библиотеку импорта - возможны варианты._ Библиотеку импорта

Comment: Если в таблице экспорта С++ с декорированием не vc++, то библиотеку импорта сделать не получится.  Если в таблице экспорта С++ с декорированием vc++, то можно сгенерировать библиотеку импорта посредством утилит dumpbin (для создания .def файла из таблицы экспорта) и lib (для создания библиотеки импорта из .def файла). Если в таблице экспорта ординалы или С функции, то придется реверсить библиотеку, чтобы выяснить типы экспортируемых сущностей. Ну и еще написать соотв. заголовочные файлы.